# Suppressing all errors originating in a particular library in valgrind

Tags: valgrind, gnutls

I have a network related app that makes use of gnutls that I need to debug, but some uninitialised memory errors are causing a proliferation throughout the application that makes valgrind virtually useless.

With --track-origins=yes on it clearly shows the errors are originating in gnutls:

```
==1369==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==1369==    at 0x5FE39B7: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libgnutls.so.28.15.0)
```

I tried manually suppressing these errors using --gen-suppressions=all, but it seems I would end up suppressing errors in a large portion of my application that is built on top of gnutls.

I also tried:

```
{
   gnutls
   Memcheck:Cond
   obj:/usr/local/lib/libgnutls.so.28.15.0
}
```

This seems to not suppress anything at all. Is there any way to prevent the proliferation of errors from a particular library so I don't have to have such a large suppression file?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the library with your own class and do everything within try catch blocks. It gives you the option to ignore the errors or retry method calls.

Comment: How do try/catch blocks affect conditions that valgrind detects?